# Parameters in PnP template in JsonControlData property

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, pnp-provision

I tried to provision a modern site with a people web part.

The configuration of this web part is mainly stored in a property called `JsonControlData`. I would like to know how to properly add parameters to this in the template.

The example below is wrong, because the `{parameter:name}` and other parameters are displayed as text in the site when I apply the template:

```
<pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="People" JsonControlData="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;7f718435-ee4d-431c-bdbf-9c4ff326f46e&quot;, &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;2c0ce1ac-0a27-42be-a612-1ddd93cb4f39&quot;, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;People&quot;, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;Display selected people and their profiles&quot;, &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.3&quot;, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;layout&quot;:1,&quot;persons&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;
{parameter:email}&quot;,&quot;upn&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;role&quot;:&quot;
{parameter:role}&quot;,&quot;department&quot;:&quot;
{parameter:department}&quot;,&quot;phone&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sip&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]}, &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: {&quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},&quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;persons[0].name&quot;:&quot;{parameter:name}&quot;,&quot;persons[0].email&quot;:&quot;{parameter:email}&quot;},&quot;imageSources&quot;:{},&quot;links&quot;:{}}, &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {}, &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}}" ControlId="7f718435-ee4d-431c-bdbf-9c4ff326f46e" Order="1" Column="3" />
```

Update:
I managed to set some of the properties like:

```
        <pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="People" ControlId="7f718435-ee4d-431c-bdbf-9c4ff326f46e" Order="1" Column="3">
          <pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
            <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="id" Value="7f718435-ee4d-431c-bdbf-9c4ff326f46e" />
            <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="instanceId" Value="2c0ce1ac-0a27-42be-a612-1ddd93cb4f39" />
            <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="title" Value="People" />
            <pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="dataVersion" Value="1.3" />
        </pnp:CanvasControlProperties>
      </pnp:CanvasControl>
```

But I cannot set the nested properties under the `properties` key.

The following didn't work:

```
<pnp:CanvasControlProperty Key="properties.persons[0].id" Value="myemail@mydomain.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the `JsonControlData` of a `Person` Web part with three people, formatted to be almost readable:

```
<pnp:CanvasControl WebPartType="People" 
JsonControlData="
{
    &quot;id&quot;: &quot;7f718435-ee4d-431c-bdbf-9c4ff326f46e&quot;,
    &quot;instanceId&quot;: &quot;0c137a10-dda7-415d-b518-99479e68e170&quot;,
    &quot;title&quot;: &quot;Persons&quot;,
    &quot;description&quot;: &quot;DESCRIPTION&quot;,
    &quot;dataVersion&quot;: &quot;1.3&quot;,
    &quot;properties&quot;: 
    {
        &quot;layout&quot;:1,
        &quot;persons&quot;:
        [
            {
            &quot;id&quot;:&quot;FIRSTPERSONEMAIL@EMAIL.COM&quot;,
            &quot;upn&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;role&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;department&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;phone&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;sip&quot;:&quot;&quot;
            },
            {
            &quot;id&quot;:&quot;SECONDPERSONEMAIL@EMAIL.COM&quot;,
            &quot;upn&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;role&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;department&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;phone&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;sip&quot;:&quot;&quot;
            },
            {
            &quot;id&quot;:&quot;THIRDPERSONEMAIL@EMAIL.COM&quot;,
            &quot;upn&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;role&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;department&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;phone&quot;:&quot;&quot;,
            &quot;sip&quot;:&quot;&quot;
            }
        ],
        &quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;
    },
    &quot;serverProcessedContent&quot;: 
    {
        &quot;htmlStrings&quot;:{},
        &quot;searchablePlainTexts&quot;:
        {
            &quot;persons[0].name&quot;:&quot;FIRSTPERSON_NAME&quot;,
            &quot;persons[1].name&quot;:&quot;SECONDPERSON_NAME&quot;,
            &quot;persons[2].name&quot;:&quot;THIRDPERSON_NAME&quot;,
            &quot;persons[0].email&quot;:&quot;FIRSTPERSONEMAIL@EMAIL.COM&quot;,
            &quot;persons[1].email&quot;:&quot;SECONDPERSONEMAIL@EMAIL.COM&quot;,
            &quot;persons[2].email&quot;:&quot;THIRDPERSONEMAIL@EMAIL.COM&quot;
        },
        &quot;imageSources&quot;:{},
        &quot;links&quot;:{}
    },
    &quot;dynamicDataPaths&quot;: {},
    &quot;dynamicDataValues&quot;: {}
 }" ControlId="7f718435-ee4d-431c-bdbf-9c4ff326f46e" Order="1" Column="2" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how will this help with my question of provisioning.

Comment: Copy, paste and insert the emails and you got a working provisioning template for people web parts.

Comment: The question is how to add parameters properly to fill the web part dynamically.